# In-core inode list and disk inode list

Tags: unix, filesystems, inode

Kindly tell me the difference between In-core inode list and disk inode list with reference to Unix File System.

Also, kindly direct me to the links where i can get more info on this.

Thanks,LinuxPenseur

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From http://www.cs.iastate.edu/~cs554/NOTES/RPC/UNIXfilesystem.pdf (3rd page):

> • on-disk inode refers to inode stored in disk within the inode list
>
> • in-core inode refers to inode stored in memory when a file is open

Answer (score 6):

The inode is a data structure that describes a file. The inode is actually a structure on filesystem. To open a file, the kernel copies the inode into memory. As the file changes, the in-core inode is updated usually more often than the on-disk copy. And the in-core inode has a few extra fields that are only needed while the file is opened. This over-simplifies things a little bit, but I think it's enough for now.
----lok!------

Answer (score 1):

Basically the question has been answered. I would like to add in some of my views.

In - core inode refers to inode which is present in the main memory.The kernel uses it whenever a process wants to manipulate a file in the secondary memory.It is a dynamic entity.

On- disk inode is a static entity & is present only in the Secondary memory.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

" Difference between in-core Inode and disk Inode

The inode is a data structure that describes everything about a file other than their name.
When a file is opened then the kernel copies the inode into memory. As the file changes, the
in-core inode is updated usually more often than the on-disk copy. And the in-core inode has a few extra fields that are only needed while the file is opened.